# Bitcoind testnet mode No block source available 0 connection

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

In fact I know this question is hard to answer as it has many reasons for, but is there any clear way to check in "steps" how to configure or know why such a behavior happen and what is the other available solutions?

Comment: Call `bitcoind -debug=net -printtoconsole` and update your question with (all) the output you get up to the point it gets stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, download the wallet, open it up and run it.
    Next, click on the bottom left windows symbol and in the search bar type %appdata% (include the percent signs) and hit enter OR click on the Roaming folder
    Find the name of the wallet/coin that you just downloaded and open up the file
    Right click in a vacant spot and choose "New" then choose "Text Document" and open up a blank document.
    Now you make your conf file. (I keep a generic one on hand and just copy and paste... add in any addnodes if they are supplied) Should look something like this:
    rpcuser=miner            Can be any name or letter(s) or number you want, just make sure it matches your batch file
    rpcpassword=x                       Can be any name or letter(s) or number you want, just make sure it matches your batch file
    rpcallowip=127.0.0.1              Local address to mine off your own computer
    rpcport=21213                       Pretty much any port number (I just use the same port for what ever coin I mine unless I must use a different one).
    daemon=1
    gen=0
    listen=1
    addnode=**if they give you one put it here**
    Save the file as **coinname**.conf
    Now it gets a little tricky here. It may save the file as **coinname**.conf.txt and that will NOT work. If it saves it with .TXT at the end, just right click on the file, choose  rename and delete the .txt (make sure you delete the .  (dot) as well as the TXT)
    Now you should be finished there and can close up that file, You can also close the wallet because if it needed an addnode, it has NOT synced up yet anyways.

The wallet should now be set up. The next time you open it, it should sync if it needed an addnode and it should be ready for solo mining because of the conf file you made.
Now we need to set up your miner (I use CGminer... so I am going to go with that).
So to set up the CGminer I make a batch file by going into the CGminer folder and right clicking on a blank space (after you made the first one you can just copy and rename the next ones but we are not there yet). and select *New* and then select *Text Document* to open a blank document.
Now you type in your information that you want, should look something like this:

cgminer.exe --scrypt -o http:// 127.0.0.1:21213 -u Miner -p x

Notice the address (-o http:// 127.0.0.1:21213) is the same as the rpcallowip and rpcport numbers in our config file.
Also notice that the user name (-u Miner) and the password (-p x) are the same as the ones we put in our config file as well. (please note that the -u indicates user name and the -p indicates password and are NEEDED in your batch file.

Ok, so now you made your batch file... you just need to save it and rename it to **Coin name**.bat (dot BAT) and that makes it a batch file.
Once you are done there... it should be that all you need to do is click the batch file, and it will automatically open your miner with the settings you put in, (in this case, its set up to solo mine off your own computer)

[Bitcoin node list](https://blockchain.info/ip-log)

[See all the file name extension](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7)

Comment: This works with any type of cryptocoin and all the algorithms!!